# How can I get gmake to output return codes for all commands without modifying makefile

Tags: makefile, return-value, gnu-make

How can I get `gmake` to output exit status codes for all commands without modifying the `Makefile`? If modifying the `Makefile` was an option, something like the following is possible:

```
$(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS); echo $$?
```

Another way that I've found so far is to wrap the command I'm running. For example, if

```
gcc -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)
```

is the command running, and the current directory `.` is at front of the `PATH` variable, then you can create a script called `gcc` in the current directory with the following contents:

```
/usr/bin/gcc "$@"; echo $?
```

I'm wondering if there is a better, less hackish, more elegant solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that all your suggested workarounds are broken: because you are now running `echo` as the last command in the recipe, the recipe will always exit with the return code of `echo`, which is always success.  If you make your changes as described, in other words, make will no longer detect any build failures and treat every command as a success.

To make this work you must write something like:

```
$(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS); r=$$?; echo $$r; exit $$r
```

The only "clean" way that I can think of to do this without changing the makefile, yet still handling all the different targets, would be to change the `SHELL` make uses with one of your own that behaves how you want.  Unfortunately this is a bit tricky, but something like this should work:

```
$ cat shexit
#!/bin/sh
/bin/sh "$@"
r=$?
echo $r
exit $r

$ chmod 755 shexit

$ make SHELL=$(pwd)/shexit
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Just a follow up question; how can I add a counter to keep track of step numbers?

Comment: You can't do that without modifying the makefile.  At least, not if you want to support parallel builds.  The shell command is a separate process so ANY change you make to it will be lost when it exits, so you can't use the environment, etc. to count things.  The only possible way to do it without modifying the makefile at all would be to keep the count in a temporary file, but if you used parallel builds then you'd have a problem with parallel jobs accessing the temporary file: you'd have to use flock(1) maybe.  If you're willing to change the makefile it can be done pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

Make fails a target if any command returns non-zero, and prints what that non-zero exit code was. So, for any command with no printed exit code, you already know what it was - zero. If simply having this knowledge is insufficient, it's pretty easy to fix. If you can distinguish the commands that make prints from other output, you could easily enough run a `sed` script to stick `0` in the right place for commands that were successful.